# Simple JQuery Animation Queue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

A little help here to figure out what error  to run this piece of code:

```
$('p:first').animate({
    height: '+=100px',
    color:'green'
},{
    duration: 'slow',
    easing: 'swing',
    complete: function(){alert('done!');},
    queue: 'false'
});
```

I include the plugins below but the animation does not execute.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.color.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I already checked it with firebug and also appear with no error..

Comment: do you include `jQuery` library?

Comment: @thecodeparadox : yes sorry: i'll edit it..

Comment: look in browser console at error regarding color script....jQuery must load before plugins and code that are dependent on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queue: `false`
```

should be

```
queue: false // without quote
```

**Full code**

```
$('p:first').animate({
    height: '+=100px',
    color:'green'
},{
    duration: 'slow',
    easing: 'swing',
    complete: function(){alert('done!');},
    queue: false // without quote
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/372/)**

#### Note

`jquer.color` should include after `jquery library`. So the inclusion order should look like:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: @Jed check my answer with demo